# Create table in php from sqlite3 database

Tags: php, html, database, sqlite

I am attempting to create a html table using php to retrieve data from an SQLite3 database. The database contains a table of users and bills with information in each row about each. I am trying to display the table but the page will not load and I cannot figure out what is wrong in my code. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

My database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE users(id integer primary key, Username varchar(15), FirstName varchar(15), LastName varchar(15), Email varchar(50), HouseName varchar(20), Phone integer, salt varchar(50), Encrypted_password varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE bills(id integer primary key, HouseName varchar(20), Bill varchar(20), Amount real, PaidBy varchar(20), Date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

html/php table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th width="100"> Bill</th>
  <th width="100">Amount </th>
  <th width="100">Paid By</th>
  <th width="100">Added On</th>
  <th width="100">You owe</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
  require ‘session.php’; 
  require ‘database.php’;
  while(($row = $querybills->fetchArray())) {
  $html .= "<tr><td>"$row['Bill']"</td><td>"$row['Amount']"</td><td>"$row['PaidBy']"</td><td>"$row['Date']"</td><td>"$row['Amount'] / $billscount"</td>   </tr>";
  }
  echo $html;
?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'database.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  $db = new Database();
  $queryuser = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE(id = '".$_SESSION['id']."')";
  $user = $db->querySingle($queryuser);

  $querybills = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bills WHERE(HouseName == ".$user['HouseName'].")");
  $bill = $db->querySingle($querybills);
  $billscount = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE(HouseName == ".$user['HouseName'].")");
} else {
  header('Location:login.php');
}
?>
```

database.php:

```
<?php
class Database {

private $database;

function __construct() {
    $this->database = $this->getConnection();
}

function __destruct() {
    $this->database->close();
}

function exec($query) {
    $this->database->exec($query);
}

function query($query) {
    $result = $this->database->query($query);
    return $result;
}

function querySingle($query) {
    $result = $this->database->querySingle($query,true);
    return $result;
}

function prepare($query) {
    return $this->database->prepare($query);
}

function escapeString($string) {
    return $this->database->escapeString($string);
}

private function getConnection() {
    $conn = new SQLite3('bills.db');
    return $conn;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Enable Strict standards in your php file and post the error you're see. either (a) write the following in your calling page: `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` or (b) modify your `php.ini`, search for `error_reporting` set it to: `error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT`. Then restart your webserver, then share the error with us.

Comment: I've added error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); to the calling page but where are the errors supposed to show up? All i get is a google chrome server error.

Comment: If you have server access or are working locally, try adding it to the `php.ini` file. Alternatively, if you are working remotely, go to the server logs in your control panel (if you have access)

Comment: I am working remotely but cannot access the server logs as I am not the admin of the server. If there aren't any glaring mistakes in the code above I may be able to try and debug it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to intialize your $html outside your loop, as it is only in scope of the `while`... unless you define it in your required files.

So you need to initialize it outside, so it is visible to the `echo` statement.

Also ... In the line with

```
$html .= "<tr><td>"$row['Bill']"</td><td>"$row['Amount']"</td><td>"$row['PaidBy']"</td><td>"$row['Date']"</td><td>"$row['Amount'] / $billscount"</td>   </tr>";
```

You are not concatenating (using the `.` operator) your variables to your string.

Change to this:

```
$html .= "<tr><td>" . $row['Bill'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Amount']" . </td><td>" . $row['PaidBy'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td><td>" . ($row['Amount'] / $billscount) ."</td>   </tr>";
```

So your new code can be

```
<table>
  <thead>
<tr>
  <th width="100"> Bill</th>
  <th width="100">Amount </th>
  <th width="100">Paid By</th>
  <th width="100">Added On</th>
  <th width="100">You owe</th>
</tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php
  require ‘session.php’; 
  require ‘database.php’;

    $html = '';


    while(($row = $querybills->fetchArray())){
        $html .= "<tr><td>" . $row['Bill'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Amount'] . "</td><td>" . $row['PaidBy'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td><td>" . ($row['Amount'] / $billscount) ."</td>   </tr>";
    }
    echo $html;

?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```